# Save Excel Export to File Location PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to get the code below to save to a file location on the server, can anyone help. Currently it just downloads via browser but i want to run a cron and save in a file location.

```
<?php
// Connection 

$conn=mysql_connect('**','**','**');
$db=mysql_select_db('SHP',$conn);

$filename = "stockbook.xls"; // File Name
// Download file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
file_put_contents("http://kempfenterprises.com/dash/reports/stockbook.xls");
$user_query = mysql_query("select * from troy.stockbook ");
// Write data to file
$flag = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_query)) {
if (!$flag) {
    // display field/column names as first row
     echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
     }
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Use fopen() to open a file for writing; switch your echo and implode to use fputcsv() to write your lines too that file; and use fclose() to close it when you've finished writing

Comment: how would i use fopen, do i need to remove my echo completely

Comment: PHP has some incredibly useful documentation with detailed explanation of all functions like [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and [fclose()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php).... learn to use that documentation before asking questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_put_contents` to write file in server.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect('**','**','**');
$db=mysql_select_db('SHP',$conn);

$sql = "select * from troy.stockbook";
$qur = mysql_query($sql);

// Enable to download this file
$filename = "stockbook.csv";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");

$display = fopen("php://output", 'w');

$flag = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qur)) {
if(!$flag) {
  // display field/column names as first row
  fputcsv($display, array_keys($row), ",", '"');
  $flag = true;
}
fputcsv($display, array_values($row), ",", '"');
  }

fclose($display);
?>
```

this is using fopen how can i now add a location where i want to save it

Comment: The first option for `fopen()` is a filename. You're using `php://input` as the filename; change that to any directory path/filename that you want on your server; then drop the two header lines, because you're not sending it to a browser anymore

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark, i have removed the headers and and changed the output to read "http://kempfenterprises.com/dash/reports/" but im still not getting the file to save in that location. Is the location in the right format?

Comment: No, that's just a folder.... you need to provide "foldername/filename.extension" as the argument passed to save

Comment: i have changed this so the location is http://kempfenterprises.com/dash/reports/test.csv but the file is still not saving to the location, any ideas

Comment: Check that the folder exists; check that you have the relevant privileges to write to it; enable PHP error logging

Comment: Ok thanks for your help Mark, could you possibly help me with a query issue as well?

Comment: For a query issue, you're probably best asking another question

Comment: Ok thanks, the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898316/totalling-query-in-last-row
if you wanted to take a look anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('**', '**', '**');
$db = mysql_select_db('SHP', $conn);
$sql = "select * from troy.stockbook";
$qur = mysql_query($sql);
// Enable to download this file
$filename = "stockbook.csv";
$display = fopen("php://output", 'w');
$data = "";
$flag = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qur)) {
    if (!$flag) {
        // display field/column names as first row
        $data.=implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
        $flag = true;
    }
    $data.=implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
}
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Hi Nalini U, welcome. Please consider adding more information.