# Totalling query in last row

Tags: mysql

This query will return a list of engineer names with test results for what they have tested in the last hour, what is faulty, what's is working and the total for each engineer.

I want to be able to add a row at the bottom which will total these amounts but am struggling, any one have any suggestions?

```
select distinct qcheck.checkby,
                ifnull(fully,0)    as fully,
                ifnull(faulty,0)   as faulty,
                ifnull(lasthour,0) as lasthour,
                ifnull(total,0)    as total 
from            qcheck
left join       (
                select   count(*) AS fully,
                         checkby,
                         qcheck.id 
                from     qcheck
                where    result = 'fully tested & working' 
                and      date(finishdate) = CURDATE() 
                group by checkby) AS fw 
             on fw.checkby=qcheck.checkby
left join (
                select   count(*) AS faulty,
                         checkby,
                         qcheck.id 
                from     qcheck
                where    result = 'faulty' 
                and      date(finishdate) = CURDATE() 
                group by checkby) AS ff 
             on ff.checkby=qcheck.checkby
left join (
                select   count(*) AS Lasthour,
                         checkby,
                         qcheck.id from qcheck
                where    finishdate >= now() - interval 1 hour 
                group by checkby) AS lh 
             on lh.checkby=qcheck.checkby
left join (
                select   count(*) AS total,
                         checkby,
                         qcheck.id from qcheck
                where    date(finishdate) = CURDATE() 
                group by checkby) AS total 
             on total.checkby=qcheck.checkby
where           date(finishdate) = CURDATE() 
and             qcheck.checkby not like 'michael' 
and             qcheck.checkby not like 'chaz'
group by        qcheck.checkby
order by        total desc
```

Comment: Just make second query for totals.

Comment: yes i can right another query but i need it to be joined to the end of the table generated by this query, so the table dynamically builds depending on what engineers are working and the totals will also be in the last row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need the sub queries, you can instead do a count on a condition.

The [`with rollup`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier can be added to the `group by` clause to include the grand total. The `order by` cannot be used in the same query then, but can be applied in an outer query.

Furthermore, with the use of `coalesce` you can replace the `null` value for that total row with the label of your choice.

Finally, to still sort the total row at the end, you could add an `is null` expression in the `order by` clause, which will evaluate to `false` or `true`. The latter is ordered last.

```
select coalesce(checkby, 'Total') as checkby_or_total,
       fully,
       faulty,
       lasthour, 
       total 
from   (
        select   qcheck.checkby,
                 count(case result when 'fully tested & working' then 1 end)     as fully,
                 count(case result when 'faulty' then 1 end)                     as faulty,
                 count(case when finishdate >= now()-interval 1 hour then 1 end) as lasthour,
                 count(*) as total 
        from     qcheck
        where    date(finishdate) = CURDATE() 
        and      qcheck.checkby not like 'michael' 
        and      qcheck.checkby not like 'chaz'
        group by qcheck.checkby with rollup
        ) as main
order by    checkby is null, 
            total desc
```

Comment: This is giving me the same result for every column

Comment: Sorry, corrected. The condition must be used in  a `case when` to return something or null. Only non-null are counted.

Comment: You are a GOD!!! How can i give the last row the name Total because at the minute in the engineer name column the last row name is null

Comment: can you also "order by" discounting the last row?

Comment: I have updated my answer to achieve that. The `checkby is null` in the order clause will evaluate to false or true, making two groups, one for the total row (true), which means it will be sorted last. The total is then ordered in second place.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, I have a very very complex query that i have written do you think you could take a look at it and see if there is any room for improvement?

Comment: You can post that as a new question. But if it has no problem, and you are just wondering if it could be written in a better way, it might be better to post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Wherever you put it, I can have a look. Just post the link to it here once you have posted it.

Comment: Here is the link
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132385/query-for-working-out-amounts

Comment: As I think I answered your original question, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: Sure how do i do that, would you be able to help me with this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987945/using-rollup-with-subqueries