# Using Rollup with subqueries

Tags: mysql

This query runs multiple counts against the same table (qcheck) to give me the total number of test each engineer has done broken down into hour, day, week, month. I have also included a screen shot of results and of the data.

I want to rollup so I can get the totals but not sure how to do this when using subqueries as I can join the total to anything

[picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9TZG.png)

[Picture of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtTU0.png)

Code:

```
select coalesce(main.checkby, 'Total') as checkby_or_total,
       lfaulty,
       lfully,
       ltotal,
       dfaulty,
       dfully,
       dtotal,
       wfaulty,
       wfully,
       wtotal,
       mfaulty,
       mfully,
       mtotal
from   (
        select   qcheck.checkby,
                 count(case result when 'fully tested & working' then 1 end)     as mfully,
                 count(case result when 'faulty' then 1 end)                     as mfaulty,
                 count(*) as mtotal
        from     qcheck
        where    YEAR(finishdate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(finishdate) = MONTH(CURDATE())
        and      qcheck.checkby not like 'michael'
        and      qcheck.checkby not like 'chaz'
        group by qcheck.checkby with rollup
        ) as main
Left join ( select   qcheck.checkby,
                 count(case result when 'fully tested & working' then 1 end)     as dfully,
                 count(case result when 'faulty' then 1 end)                     as dfaulty,
                 count(*) as dtotal
        from     qcheck
        where    finishdate >= now()-interval 12 hour
        and      qcheck.checkby not like 'michael'
        and      qcheck.checkby not like 'chaz'
        group by qcheck.checkby with rollup) as today on today.checkby =main.checkby
Left join ( select   qcheck.checkby,
                 count(case result when 'fully tested & working' then 1 end)     as wfully,
                 count(case result when 'faulty' then 1 end)                     as wfaulty,
                 count(*) as wtotal
        from     qcheck
        where    YEARWEEK(finishdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())
        and      qcheck.checkby not like 'michael'
        and      qcheck.checkby not like 'chaz'
        group by qcheck.checkby with rollup) as week on week.checkby =main.checkby
Left join ( select   qcheck.checkby,
                 count(case result when 'fully tested & working' then 1 end)     as lfully,
                 count(case result when 'faulty' then 1 end)                     as lfaulty,
                 count(*) as ltotal
        from     qcheck
        where    finishdate >= now()-interval 1 hour
        and      qcheck.checkby not like 'michael'
        and      qcheck.checkby not like 'chaz'
        group by qcheck.checkby with rollup) as month on month.checkby =main.checkby
order by    main.checkby is null,
            mtotal desc
```

Comment: Is the second picture the *desired* output, or the *current* output? If not the *desired* output, could you provide it based on the data you used in the other images? Also, please don't use images, but plain text (indent with 4 spaces for monospaced layout -- select all, press Ctrl+K to do that)

Comment: i have updated the query and also picture of results, the "picture of results" is how i want it displayed but the roll up isnt working for the last row on all columns, i would also like to have null as 0, hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rollup rows produced in the subqueries are lost because of the join condition `xxxx.checkby =main.checkby`. This condition is `false` when either side is `null`. In particular: `null = null` is `false`.

Also, you might have some border cases where you would have a week that crosses over two months and so the count on week could cover more than the count on the current month. This is not a problem in itself, but the way the `join` chain starts with the monthly count, you might miss out on some records in the weekly count. Namely a weekly record for a person that has not have a record yet in the current month, will not get counted in the week statistic.

The `null` values you get are the result of the outer (`left`) joins. When the outer join condition is false, all fields (also the counts) on the righter joined table will yield `null` when referenced.

All of the above issues can be solved by doing one big sub query, using more elaborate `case when` conditions instead of the `where` conditions:

```
select    *
from      (
          select   coalesce(checkby, 'Total') as checkby_or_total,
                   count(case when last_day(finishdate) = last_day(curdate())
                               and result = 'fully tested & working' 
                         then 1 end) as mfully,
                   count(case when last_day(finishdate) = last_day(curdate())
                               and result = 'faulty' 
                         then 1 end) as mfaulty,
                   count(case when last_day(finishdate) = last_day(curdate())
                         then 1 end) as mtotal,
                   count(case when date(finishdate) = curdate()
                               and result = 'fully tested & working' 
                         then 1 end) as dfully,
                   count(case when date(finishdate) = curdate()
                               and result = 'faulty'
                         then 1 end) as dfaulty,
                   count(case when date(finishdate) = curdate()
                         then 1 end) as dtotal,
                   count(case when yearweek(finishdate) = yearweek(curdate())
                               and result = 'fully tested & working' 
                         then 1 end) as wfully,
                   count(case when yearweek(finishdate) = yearweek(curdate())
                               and result = 'faulty'
                         then 1 end) as wfaulty,
                   count(case when yearweek(finishdate) = yearweek(curdate())
                         then 1 end) as wtotal,
                   count(case when finishdate >= now() - interval 1 hour
                               and result = 'fully tested & working' 
                         then 1 end) as lfully,
                   count(case when finishdate >= now() - interval 1 hour
                               and result = 'faulty'
                         then 1 end) as lfaulty,
                   count(case when finishdate >= now() - interval 1 hour
                         then 1 end) as ltotal
          from     qcheck
          where    checkby not in ('michael', 'chaz')
          group by checkby with rollup) as main
order by  checkby_or_total = 'Total',
          mtotal desc
```

I have also introduced some different conditions:

- The month condition can be made more efficiently with `last_day(finishdate) = last_day(curdate())`
- The same-day condition could be `date(finishdate) = curdate()`, although that is not exactly the same as the condition you used. But maybe you want to consider this one.